# Writing Go object code that respects Go guidelines

Tags: performance, object-oriented, programming-challenge, go, pointers

I'm learning Go and I wrote this for a programming challenge. It is working (building and running) but I feel the code is not what Go code should be:

- Am I using the `struct` element correctly? especially struct methods?
- In the `playTurn()` method, I reassign results (else not taken into account) because scope. How to write it better? Pointer?
- I am struggling with `int`, `float64` and casting all the time. What's the good practice in this context were I need float for precision in-between but inputs and outputs are int?

**What does this code do?** It plays a 2D racing game between 4 pod-racers. 
In an infinite loop controlled by the programming challenge server, this code reads inputs about pods states (cf. comments) and outputs the next action my pods should take.
The part I want to discuss is the simulation part: the code also forecast what my pod state should be after taking the next action. 
I don't really care if there are bugs right now (since I am writing unit tests to catch them), still I am open to any criticism.

However, I am worried I didn't write in a **Go-like manner**. See my 3 questions. As a consequence of a better Go code, I expect better performances.

Full script:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

// Pod is life
type Pod struct {
    position                Dot
    vx, vy, angle, nextCpID int
    hasShieldOn             bool
}

func squaredDist(a, b Dot) int {
    return (a.x-b.x)*(a.x-b.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y)
}
func distance(a, b Dot) float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(float64(squaredDist(a, b)))
}

func (pod Pod) getAngle(p Dot) float64 {
    d := distance(p, pod.position)
    dx := float64(p.x-pod.position.x) / d
    dy := float64(p.y-pod.position.y) / d
    a := math.Acos(dx) * 180.0 / math.Pi

    // If the point I want is below me, I have to shift the angle for it to be correct
    if dy < 0 {
        a = 360.0 - a
    }
    return a
}

func (pod Pod) diffAngle(p Dot) float64 {
    a := pod.getAngle(p)
    pangle := float64(pod.angle)

    right := 0.0
    if pangle <= a {
        right = a - pangle
    } else {
        right = 360.0 - pangle + a
    }

    left := 0.0
    if pangle >= a {
        left = pangle - a
    } else {
        left = pangle + 360.0 - a
    }

    if right < left {
        return right
    }
    return -left
}

func (pod Pod) rotate(p Dot) int {
    a := pod.diffAngle(p)

    // Can't turn more than 18° in one turn !
    if a > 18.0 {
        a = 18.0
    } else if a < -18.0 {
        a = -18.0
    }

    pod.angle += int(math.Round(a))

    if pod.angle >= 360.0 {
        pod.angle = pod.angle - 360.0
    } else if pod.angle < 0.0 {
        pod.angle += 360.0
    }
    return pod.angle
}

func (pod Pod) boost(t int) (int, int) {
    if pod.hasShieldOn {
        return pod.vx, pod.vy
    }
    pangle := float64(pod.angle)
    pod.vx += int(math.Round(math.Cos(pangle) * float64(t)))
    pod.vy += int(math.Round(math.Sin(pangle) * float64(t)))
    return pod.vx, pod.vy
}

// t shoud become a float later on
func (pod Pod) move(t int) (int, int) {
    pod.position.x += pod.vx * t
    pod.position.y += pod.vy * t
    return pod.position.x, pod.position.y
}

func (pod Pod) endTurn() (int, int) {
    // todo rounding position if needed
    pod.vx = int(float64(pod.vx) * 0.85)
    pod.vy = int(float64(pod.vy) * 0.85)
    return pod.vx, pod.vy
}

func (pod Pod) playTurn(p Dot, t int) {
    pod.angle = pod.rotate(p)
    pod.vx, pod.vy = pod.boost(t)
    pod.position.x, pod.position.y = pod.move(1)
    pod.vx, pod.vy = pod.endTurn()
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "\nPredicted Pod position : ")
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "\n(%d, %d) speed (%d,%d)", pod.position.x, pod.position.y, pod.vx, pod.vy)
}

// Dot is king
type Dot struct {
    x, y int
}

func main() {
    var laps int
    fmt.Scan(&laps)

    var checkpointCount int
    fmt.Scan(&checkpointCount)
    var checkPoints []Dot
    for i := 0; i < checkpointCount; i++ {
        var checkpointX, checkpointY int
        fmt.Scan(&checkpointX, &checkpointY)
        checkPoints = append(checkPoints, Dot{checkpointX, checkpointY})
    }
    var myPods [2]Pod
    var itsPods [2]Pod
    for {
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            // x: x position of your pod
            // y: y position of your pod
            // vx: x speed of your pod
            // vy: y speed of your pod
            // angle: angle of your pod
            // nextCheckPointId: next check point id of your pod
            var x, y, vx, vy, angle, nextCheckPointID int
            fmt.Scan(&x, &y, &vx, &vy, &angle, &nextCheckPointID)
            myPods[i] = Pod{Dot{x, y}, vx, vy, angle, nextCheckPointID, false}
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "\nActual Pod position : ")
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "\n(%d, %d) speed (%d,%d)", myPods[i].position.x, myPods[i].position.y, myPods[i].vx, myPods[i].vy)
        }
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            // x2: x position of the opponent's pod
            // y2: y position of the opponent's pod
            // vx2: x speed of the opponent's pod
            // vy2: y speed of the opponent's pod
            // angle2: angle of the opponent's pod
            // nextCheckPointId2: next check point id of the opponent's pod
            var x2, y2, vx2, vy2, angle2, nextCheckPointID2 int
            fmt.Scan(&x2, &y2, &vx2, &vy2, &angle2, &nextCheckPointID2)
            itsPods[i] = Pod{Dot{x2, y2}, vx2, vy2, angle2, nextCheckPointID2, false}
        }

        // fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "Debug messages...")
        for _, pod := range myPods {
            nx := checkPoints[pod.nextCpID].x - 3*pod.vx
            ny := checkPoints[pod.nextCpID].y - 3*pod.vy
            // Predicting where my pods will be next turn:
            pod.playTurn(Dot{nx, ny}, 100)
            //
            fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(nx) + " " + strconv.Itoa(ny) + " 100")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this code do?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: thanks for the feedback & the edit. Should I split it into 3 posts : OOP in Go, is it a pointers use case, how to manage int and float64 ?

Comment: @Poutrathor I've not taken the time to read through your code yet, but I did notice the use of value receivers. It doesn't make sense to have functions like `move` on a type, and in those funcs statements like `pod.position.x += pod.vx * t` (assigning values), unless you're dealing with pointer receivers. Otherwise, you'd just be reassigning values on a copy, but the object itself is never changed.